# No Module name Platform - C# and Python

Tags: python, c#, ironpython

I am working with python scripts and C# code and all was working well until I imported libraries like `Platform` to the Python script. No errors while running a Standalone script, however errors does appear while running the same via VS.

NuGet Package Python version : 2.7.1

Python 3.9.1 installed in the system.

```
using IronPython.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting;
using IronPython.Modules;

ScriptEngine engine = Python.CreateEngine();
 var libs = new[] {
                    "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\IronPython.2.7.11\\Lib",
                    "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\IronPython 2.7.11\\DLLs",
                    "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\IronPython 2.7.11",
                    "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\IronPython 2.7.11\\Lib\\site-packages",
                };
engine.SetSearchPaths(libs);

ScriptScope scope = engine.CreateScope();
engine.ExecuteFile(@"D:\Projects\pythonQuery.py", scope);
var result = scope.GetVariable("a");
```

pythonQuery.py

```
import platform 
from hdbcli import dbapi
import sys

a = ""
a += "helcccclo world\n"
a += "==========="
```

On running straight away using PowerShell

[image]

However, I get the following error `{"No module named platform"}` while running the same code in Visual Studio.

[image]

Comment: I've removed the ASP.NET-MVC tag because I can't see any code pertaining to ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: @Llama Kindly remove your comment as well. Thanks.

Comment: Is there a reason why this is a requirement?

Comment: Anyway, it seems likely to me that you should add your search paths as individual strings, rather than one long string with comma-separated quoted paths.

Comment: @Llama Yes, its probably the paths which is incorrect. Can you please help me. I have done some changes above. I have installed IronPython and added the paths.

Comment: If that wasn't the issue then I'm not sure I'm afraid. I've not actually used IronPython, but it just seemed to be the most obvious place that might be incorrect.